# MFC: CMFCDropDownToolBar is blank for all but the first one button

Tags: winapi, mfc, cmfctoolbar

Created a `CMFCDropDownToolBar`in `CMainFrame::OnCreate`:

```
// Loading toolbar with a single icon/entry.
if (!m_wndMyDropdownToolBar.Create(this,   
    WS_CHILD|CBRS_TOP|CBRS_TOOLTIPS|CBRS_FLYBY|CBRS_HIDE_INPLACE|CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC|   
    CBRS_GRIPPER | CBRS_BORDER_3D,   
    ID_ACTION_BUTTON) ||    
    !m_wndMyDropdownToolBar.LoadToolBar (IDR_TOOLBAR_DROPDOWNSELECT))   
{   
    TRACE0("Failed to create build toolbar\n");   
    return FALSE;      // fail to create   
}   

// build list - use existing icon
for (UINT i=0; i<2; i++) {
  CString s;
  s.Format(_T("%i: Whatever %i\n"), i, i);
  m_wndMyDropdownToolBar.InsertButton(CMFCToolBarButton(ID_COMMAND_START+i, 0, s));
};
```

Then the rest:

```
afx_msg LRESULT CMainFrame::OnToolbarReset(WPARAM idtoolbar, LPARAM)
{
  if (idtoolbar==IDR_MAINFRAME) {
    ASSERT(m_wndMyDropdownToolBar.GetSafeHwnd() != NULL);

     //-----------------------------------   
     // Replace dropdown button:   
     //-----------------------------------   
    m_wndToolBar.ReplaceButton(ID_ACTION_BUTTON_DUMMY,
                               CMFCDropDownToolbarButton(_T("Text that doesn't show anywhere"), &m_wndMyDropdownToolBar));
  }

  return 0;
}


BOOL CMainFrame::GetToolbarButtonToolTipText(CMFCToolBarButton* pButton, CString& strTTText)
{
  if (pButton->m_nID>=ID_COMMAND_START && pButton->m_nID<=ID_COMMAND_END) {
    // use text
    strTTText=pButton->m_strText;
    return TRUE;
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

It all works fine as far as the drop down shows the buttons, hovering shows the tooltip, but when you select one of the buttons added manually via the `InsertButton()` call, the button on the main toolbar is blank and no tooltips.  If I then go back and select first button (part of resource loaded), it shows the correct icon and tool tip.

What am I not doing correct?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `CMFCDropDownToolbarButton::SetDefaultCommand(UINT uiCmd)` is flawed.  If not a `bUserButton` type then it assumes the index to the `m_ImagesLocked` is by position instead of taking the buttons `iIndex`.  You can't use `bUserButton` and support `bLargeButtons` since the user buttons have to be the same size.  Also the button that sits on the main toolbar takes on the first items `m_strText` (normally empty string since loaded with toolbar) so the tooltip updates via `CMainFrame::GetToolbarButtonToolTipText()` above don't work either (it should pull in the buttons text but doesn't).   So probably test best thing to do is take `afxdropdowntoolbar.cpp` and duplicate it in the project then fix it with a new class name.  A little code bloat, if only `SetDefaultCommand()` was virtual, could fix it easily.

Also note, if using `LoadBitmap` / `LoadBitmapEx`, you should set `bLocked` to TRUE (as well as when using `InsertButton()`)

---

Have it all working the way it should have to start with, if you need this, here's the core changes:

Ugh, needed to override the protected CMFCToolBarImages::CopyTemp() so instead of having to redo almost all of the MFC toolbar support I added this hack!  I doesn't add any data members so should maintain compatiblity with CMFCToolBar.

```
class CMyToolBarImages : public CMFCToolBarImages
{
  public:

  void MyCopyTemp(CMyToolBarImages *imagesDest) const
  {
      imagesDest->Clear();
      imagesDest->m_bIsTemporary = TRUE;

      imagesDest->m_sizeImage = m_sizeImage;
      imagesDest->m_sizeImageDest = m_sizeImageDest;
      imagesDest->m_hbmImageWell = m_hbmImageWell;
      imagesDest->m_bUserImagesList = m_bUserImagesList;
      imagesDest->m_iCount = m_iCount;
      imagesDest->m_bReadOnly = TRUE;
      imagesDest->m_nBitsPerPixel = m_nBitsPerPixel;
  }
};

class CMyDropDownToolBar : public CMFCToolBar
{
   .
   .
   .
   
  virtual BOOL OnUserToolTip(CMFCToolBarButton* pButton, CString& strTTText) const;

  // HACK protected CMFCToolBarImages!!
  void CopyTempAll(CMyDropDownToolBar *desttoolbar) const
  {
    ((const CMyToolBarImages*) &m_ImagesLocked)->MyCopyTemp((CMyToolBarImages*) &desttoolbar->m_ImagesLocked);
    ((const CMyToolBarImages*) &m_ColdImagesLocked)->MyCopyTemp((CMyToolBarImages*) &desttoolbar->m_ColdImagesLocked);
    ((const CMyToolBarImages*) &m_DisabledImagesLocked)->MyCopyTemp((CMyToolBarImages*) &desttoolbar->m_DisabledImagesLocked);
    ((const CMyToolBarImages*) &m_LargeImagesLocked)->MyCopyTemp((CMyToolBarImages*) &desttoolbar->m_LargeImagesLocked);
    ((const CMyToolBarImages*) &m_LargeColdImagesLocked)->MyCopyTemp((CMyToolBarImages*) &desttoolbar->m_LargeColdImagesLocked);
    ((const CMyToolBarImages*) &m_LargeDisabledImagesLocked)->MyCopyTemp((CMyToolBarImages*) &desttoolbar->m_LargeDisabledImagesLocked);
  }
};
```

Have it call CMainFrame for tooltip:

```
BOOL CMyDropDownToolBar::OnUserToolTip(CMFCToolBarButton* pButton, CString& strTTText) const
{
    ASSERT_VALID(pButton);

    CFrameWnd* pTopFrame = AFXGetParentFrame(this);
    if (pTopFrame == NULL)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    CMyDropDownFrame* pDropFrame = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CMyDropDownFrame, pTopFrame);
    if (pDropFrame != NULL)
    {
        pTopFrame = AFXGetParentFrame(pDropFrame);
        if (pTopFrame == NULL)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    CMDIFrameWndEx* pMainFrame = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CMDIFrameWndEx, pTopFrame);
    if (pMainFrame != NULL)
    {
        return pMainFrame->GetToolbarButtonToolTipText(pButton, strTTText);
    }
    else // Maybe, SDI frame...
    {
        CFrameWndEx* pFrame = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CFrameWndEx, pTopFrame);
        if (pFrame != NULL)
        {
            return pFrame->GetToolbarButtonToolTipText(pButton, strTTText);
        }
        else // Maybe, MDIChild frame
        {
            CMDIChildWndEx* pMDIChild = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CMDIChildWndEx, pTopFrame);

            if (pMDIChild != NULL)
            {
                return pMDIChild->GetToolbarButtonToolTipText(pButton, strTTText);
            }
            else // Maybe, OLE frame...
            {
                COleIPFrameWndEx* pOleFrame = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(COleIPFrameWndEx, pFrame);
                if (pOleFrame != NULL)
                {
                    return pOleFrame->GetToolbarButtonToolTipText(pButton, strTTText);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return FALSE;

}
```

For the actual first fix needed that started this whole thing:

```
void CMyDropDownToolbarButton::SetDefaultCommand(UINT uiCmd)
{
  .
  .
  .

        if (pButton->m_nID == uiCmd)
        {
            m_bLocalUserButton = pButton->m_bUserButton;

            if (m_bLocalUserButton)
            {
                m_iSelectedImage = pButton->GetImage();
            }
            else
            {
                // FIXED HERE:
                m_iSelectedImage=pButton->GetImage();
                if (m_iSelectedImage==-1) {
                    m_iSelectedImage=iImage;
                }
            }
            // FIXED HERE:
            m_strText=pButton->m_strText;
            break;
        }

  .
  .
  .
}
```

To get the tool tips to look consistent with bold and normal, had it use CMainFrame::GetMessageString:

```
class CMyDropDownFrame : public CMiniFrameWnd
{
   .
   .
   .
   
   // For customizing the default messages on the status bar and second line of tooltip
   virtual void GetMessageString(UINT nID, CString& rMessage) const;
};


// For customizing the default messages on the status bar and second line of tooltip
void CMyDropDownFrame::GetMessageString(UINT nID, CString& rMessage) const
{
    CFrameWnd* pTopFrame = AFXGetParentFrame(this);
    if (pTopFrame == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    CMFCDropDownFrame* pDropFrame = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CMFCDropDownFrame, pTopFrame);
    if (pDropFrame != NULL)
    {
        pTopFrame = AFXGetParentFrame(pDropFrame);
        if (pTopFrame == NULL)
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    CMDIFrameWndEx* pMainFrame = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CMDIFrameWndEx, pTopFrame);
    if (pMainFrame != NULL)
    {
        pMainFrame->GetMessageString(nID, rMessage);
    return;
    }
    else // Maybe, SDI frame...
    {
        CFrameWndEx* pFrame = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CFrameWndEx, pTopFrame);
        if (pFrame != NULL)
        {
          pFrame->GetMessageString(nID, rMessage);
      return;
        }
        else // Maybe, MDIChild frame
        {
            CMDIChildWndEx* pMDIChild = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CMDIChildWndEx, pTopFrame);

            if (pMDIChild != NULL)
            {
            pMDIChild->GetMessageString(nID, rMessage);
        return;
            }
            else // Maybe, OLE frame...
            {
                COleIPFrameWndEx* pOleFrame = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(COleIPFrameWndEx, pFrame);
                if (pOleFrame != NULL)
                {
              pOleFrame->GetMessageString(nID, rMessage);
          return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also needed to change CMyDropDownFrame::OnCreate() to deal with protect member:

```
int CMyDropDownFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
  .
  .
  .
  
    // "Clone" the original toolbar:
  m_pWndOriginToolbar->CopyTempAll(&m_wndToolBar);
  /*
    m_pWndOriginToolbar->m_ImagesLocked.CopyTemp(m_wndToolBar.m_ImagesLocked);
    m_pWndOriginToolbar->m_ColdImagesLocked.CopyTemp(m_wndToolBar.m_ColdImagesLocked);
    m_pWndOriginToolbar->m_DisabledImagesLocked.CopyTemp(m_wndToolBar.m_DisabledImagesLocked);
    m_pWndOriginToolbar->m_LargeImagesLocked.CopyTemp(m_wndToolBar.m_LargeImagesLocked);
    m_pWndOriginToolbar->m_LargeColdImagesLocked.CopyTemp(m_wndToolBar.m_LargeColdImagesLocked);
    m_pWndOriginToolbar->m_LargeDisabledImagesLocked.CopyTemp(m_wndToolBar.m_LargeDisabledImagesLocked);
  */

  .
  .
  .
 };
```

Comment: Hi @user3161924, thanks for sharing the solution and you could also feel free to [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).